# jQuery - Selecting a dynamic ID once it has been appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dynamic

I am working on an application that allows tickets to be selected by both clicking and image and by drag and dropping it. I want to be able to select the id's dynamically `"id": "A" + (i+1)` resulting in A1, etc <- This is how the ids are applied, I want to be able to select the id that matches the one clicked, dropped or removed.  The images have been inserted using the following method:

```
$(window).load(function(){
td = $('#A .AS');
td.each(function (i) {
    var img = $("<img ondragstart='dragStart(event)' ondragend='dragEnd(event)'  onclick='sold(this.id)' onmouseover='over(this.id)' onmouseout='out(this.id)'/>");
    img.attr({
        "id": "A" + (i+1),
        "class": "clicks",
            "src": "images/available.gif",
            "alt": "available" + i,
            "style": "border:none",
            "title": "available",
            "draggable": "true",

    });
    $(this).append(img);
});
});
```

As you can see they have a unique id and other attributes added such as mouseover and onclick events.

Below I have disabled all attached events once the image is clicked and added to the cart. However I can't seem to be able to specifically select the id of the images using the same methods for my drag and drop or my cancel function. Basically I want to be able to select an image by it's id so that I can reinstate the disabled events, and reset both the events and image src when the image is removed from the cart. The image itself is not appended to the cart but rather it's dynamic id which displays in the cart.

```
function sold(img){
var mysrc='images/'+$(img).attr('alt');

if($(img).attr('onmouseover')==""){
$(img).attr('src',mysrc).attr('onmouseover','over(this)').attr('onmouseout','out(this)').attr('title',mytitle);

} else {
$("#"+img).attr('src','images/mine.gif');
$("#"+img).attr('onmouseover','').attr('onmouseout','');
$("#"+img).attr('onclick','');
$("#"+img).attr('title','Mine');

$("#mybillets").append("<span onclick='remove(this)' draggable='true' ondragstart='draggy(event)' ondragend='remove(this)' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+img+" </span>");

    $("#myprice").show();
}
}
```

I also am using a drag and drop method which is causing me the same problems. I cannot select the appropriate image id when dropping to set the src to the mine.png image. My code for that is as follows:

```
function dragStart(img) {   
img.dataTransfer.setData('Text/html', img.target.id); 
//alert(img.target.id);   
}


function drop(img) {
img.preventDefault();
var data = img.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");

$("#mybillets").append("<span class='empt' onclick='remove(this)' draggable='true' ondragstart='draggy(event)' ondragend='remove(this)' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+data+" </span>"); 

    $("#myprice").show();
}
```

Lastly, here is the function I am using to cancel all selected tickets. I am assuming that when if I can select the id of the image in any one of these functions that I will be able to apply it to all of the quite easily. Forgive me for the length of this post, I'm out of my depth here and would greatly appreciate any help at all!

```
function cancel(img){
$('#mybillets').empty();
$("#myprice").hide();
$('.clicks').attr('src','images/available.gif');
$('.clicks').attr('src',mysrc).attr('onmouseover','over(this)').attr('onmouseout','out(this)').attr('title',mytitle);
}
```

Note: Above I am using a class to reset all images to their original src but the cannot reinstate the attached functions with the last line. I also need to be able to select them by their id and not by a class.

Thank you for reading through all of this btw!

Comment: If you can try to make a jsbin/jsfiffle, it would be easier to show the problem that you are having.

Comment: Lots of little mistakes here, from the looks of things. I think `var mysrc='images/'+$(img).attr('alt');` should be `var mysrc=$(img).attr('src');`... `$("#"+img)` should be `$(img)`... also instead of setting event attributes like `onmouseover`, you should probably use jQuery's `on()` function... maybe you should open your debug console, step through this code, and check what the values of certain things are along the way.

Comment: @Jason , a demo JSFiddle would be really helpful .

Comment: You're right, I know there are a fair few mistakes. I only started this project yesterday and am rushing through someone else's code, I also have very little experience with this. I fixed the variable as you suggested but `$("#"+img)` is required for the functions to work I'm not sure why. I agree that I shouldn't really be using event attributes but I'm required to do so as part of the project for some odd reason. I can probably do up a jsfiddle tomorrow as it is now 6am where I live.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        function ds(){
            alert("ds");
        }
        function de(){
            alert("de");
        }
        function ck(){
            alert("ck");
        }
        function mout(){
            alert("mout");
        }
        function mover(){
            alert("mover");
        }

        td = $('#A .AS');
        td.each(function (i) {
            var img = $("<img/>");
            img.attr({
                "id": "A" + (i+1),
                "class": "clicks",
                "src": "images/available.gif",
                "alt": "available" + i,
                "style": "border:none",
                "title": "available",
                "draggable": "true",

            });

            img.bind("dragstart", ds);
            img.bind("dragend", de);
            img.bind("click", ck);
            img.bind("mouseover", mover);
            img.bind("mouseout", mout);

            $(this).append(img);

        });    

    });

</script>
```

Comment: with this code you should be able to call the IDs after they have been appended by using i.e. $('#A2')

Comment: I am looking to call the id's dynamically and not individually as I want to apply a function that will do something with the specific id that is selected by the user. Row A is only one of many. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. When the image is clicked the id is displayed as text and I want to have a function that will apply to only the id or ids that are selected. Such as enable/disable their events and display an alternate image when selected.

Comment: Currently I have the latter working for the click function but not the drag and drop as I cannot select the particular id with the same method as the click function. `$("#"+img)` works for mover, mout, and click but no other functions that are fired by different elements. Get me?